# PyTorch: Trying to backward through the graph a second time, but the buffers have already been freed. Specify retain_graph=True

Tags: python, neural-network, pytorch, backpropagation

This is an error message I get as I work with some synthetic data. I am a bit puzzled because the error persists although I do what I am advised to do.  Could it somehow be related to the fact that I do not specify a batch?  Would the use of PyTorch Dataset relieve the problem?

Here is my code (I am new in PyTorch, just learning it now) -- it should be reproducible:

## Data Creation:

```
x, y = np.meshgrid(np.random.randn(100) , np.random.randn(100))    
z = 2 * x + 3 * y + 1.5 * x * y - x ** 2 - y**2
X = x.ravel().reshape(-1, 1)
Y = y.ravel().reshape(-1, 1)    
Z = z.ravel().reshape(-1, 1)    
U = np.concatenate([X, Y], axis = 1)    
U = torch.tensor(U, requires_grad=True)    
Z = torch.tensor(Z, requires_grad=True)    
V = []

for i in range(U.shape[0]):        
    u = U[i, :]  
    u1 = u.view(-1, 1) @ u.view(1, -1)    
    u1 = u1.triu()    
    ones = torch.ones_like(u1)    
    mask = ones.triu()    
    mask = (mask == 1)    
    u2 = torch.masked_select(u1, mask)    
    u3 = torch.cat([u, u2])    
    u3 = u3.view(1, -1)    
    V.append(u3)

V = torch.cat(V, dim = 0)
```

## Training a Model

```
from torch import nn    
from torch import optim    
net = nn.Sequential(nn.Linear(V.shape[1], 1))    
criterion = nn.MSELoss()
optimizer = optim.SGD(net.parameters(), lr=0.001, momentum=0.9)

for epoch in range(50):  # loop over the dataset multiple times    
    running_loss = 0.0        
    i = 0
    for inputs , labels in zip(V, Z):
        # get the inputs; data is a list of [inputs, labels]

        # zero the parameter gradients
        optimizer.zero_grad()

        # forward + backward + optimize
        outputs = net(inputs)
        loss = criterion(outputs, labels)

        loss.backward(retain_graph = True)

        optimizer.step()

        # print statistics
        running_loss += loss.item()

        i += 1

        if i % 2000 == 1999:    # print every 2000 mini-batches
            print('[%d, %5d] loss: %.3f' %
                  (epoch + 1, i + 1, running_loss / 2000))
            running_loss = 0.0

print('Finished Training')
```

## Error Message:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-143-2454f4bb70a5> in <module>
     25 
     26 
---> 27         loss.backward(retain_graph = True)
     28 
     29         optimizer.step()

~\Anaconda3\envs\torch\lib\site-packages\torch\tensor.py in backward(self, gradient, retain_graph, create_graph)
    193                 products. Defaults to ``False``.
    194         """
--> 195         torch.autograd.backward(self, gradient, retain_graph, create_graph)
    196 
    197     def register_hook(self, hook):

~\Anaconda3\envs\torch\lib\site-packages\torch\autograd\__init__.py in backward(tensors, grad_tensors, retain_graph, create_graph, grad_variables)
     97     Variable._execution_engine.run_backward(
     98         tensors, grad_tensors, retain_graph, create_graph,
---> 99         allow_unreachable=True)  # allow_unreachable flag
    100 
    101 

RuntimeError: Trying to backward through the graph a second time, but the buffers have already been freed. Specify retain_graph=True when calling backward the first time.
```

Could you explain the error and fix the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presumably, you haven't re-run the data creation code again after setting `retain_graph=True`, as it is in a IPython REPL. It would work with that, but in nearly all cases, setting `retain_graph=True` is not the appropriate solution.

The problem in your case, is that you have set `requires_grad=True` for `U`, which means that everything that involved `U` in the data creation, will be recorded in the computational graph and when `loss.backward()` is called, the gradients will propagate through all of these up to `U`. After the first time, all buffers for the gradients of those will have been freed, and a second backward will fail.

Neither `U` nor `Z` should have `requires_grad=True`, as they are not being optimised/learned. Only the learned parameters (parameters given to the optimiser) should have `requires_grad=True` and generally, you don't have to set it manually either, since [`nn.Parameter`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#torch.nn.Parameter) handles that automatically.

You should also ensure that the tensors you create from NumPy data have type `torch.float` (float32) as NumPy's float array will usually be float64, which are mostly unnecessary and just slower compared to float32, especially on the GPU.

```py
U = torch.tensor(U, dtype=torch.float)

Z = torch.tensor(Z, dtype=torch.float)
```

And remove the `retain_graph=True` from the backward call:

```py
loss.backward()
```